# Passing cert and key as der_bin() in Erlang with ssl

Tags: ssl, erlang

I've taken the certificate and key from the PEM file and decoded the base64 to binary and put them into `Cert` and `Key`.

Then I have the following code to open a connection.

```
make_connection(Cert, Key) ->
    Options = [{cert, Cert}, {key, Key}, {mode, binary}],
    Timeout = 1000,
    % {ok, Socket} replaced for debugging...
    Socket = ssl:connect(?PUSH_SERVER_HOST, ?PUSH_SERVER_PORT,
            Options, Timeout),
    Socket.
```

Calling `make_connection(Cert, Key)` returns `{error, {eoptions, {key, <<...>>}}}`.

When I replace `Cert` and `Key` with the path to the PEM file, and `Options = [{certfile, ... keyfile ...}]`, it works and creates the SSL socket as intended.

So am I missing anything with the usage of `cert` and `key` alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [ssl.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/ssl/src/ssl.erl) file from the `ssl` application, it seems like you are supposed to use a tuple as your `Key`, rather than the binary:

```
validate_option(key, {KeyType, Value}) when is_binary(Value),
                       KeyType == rsa;
                       KeyType == dsa ->
    {KeyType, Value};
```

Where the type of the key is specified. It seems there's a bug in [the documentation for the connect function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#connect-3), where it says that you are supposed to use a binary (der_bin()) as your Key.